# Multiple if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have if cause:

```
if(
                (attackX > enemies[enemy].posX && attackX < enemies[enemy].posX + enemies[enemy].width) || (attackX + 32 > enemies[enemy].posX && attackX + 32 < enemies[enemy].posX + enemies[enemy].width)
                &&
                (attackY > enemies[enemy].posY && attackY < enemies[enemy].posY + enemies[enemy].height) || (attackY + 32 > enemies[enemy].posY && attackY + 32 < enemies[enemy].posY + enemies[enemy].height)
            ){ //CODE }

console.log(attackX > enemies[enemy].posX && attackX < enemies[enemy].posX + enemies[enemy].width); //true
        console.log(attackX + 32 > enemies[enemy].posX && attackX + 32 < enemies[enemy].posX + enemies[enemy].width); //false
        console.log(attackY > enemies[enemy].posY && attackY < enemies[enemy].posY + enemies[enemy].height); //false
        console.log(attackY + 32 > enemies[enemy].posY && attackY + 32 < enemies[enemy].posY + enemies[enemy].height); //false
```

In that situation if work, but I don't know why (there is AND operator)

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [operator precendence](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

The && has higher precendence and thereby is evaluated first -> you get
`true || (false && false) || false` which results in `true`. To fix this issues put your `||` statement groups in brackets.